# ArrayList#size() is more than actual number of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have an ArrayList in my Android app, and it has 2 items in it. However, its size method returns 3. I know it sounds really simply and stupid, but here is how it goes:

[image]

Why would this happen? How can an ArrayList's size return an incorrect number? This causes a null pointer exception when I'm iterating the list.

Comment: IntelliJ has a setting about hiding `null`  values. Right click the variables section in the debugger and choose `Customize Data Views...`. There is an option there for `Hide null array elements` that you should make sure is unticked.

Comment: @Oli it was it. it's sad that they have this extremely counter-intuitive setting turned on by default.

Comment: @Oli could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it, as it solved my problem.

Comment: Done. I agree, having it default on is a really odd choice. I stumbled across this solution when I had the same problem as you.

Comment: @Oli yeah, definitely a cool feature, but equally confusing if you don't know about it :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IntelliJ has a setting about hiding `null`  values. Right click the variables section in the debugger and choose `Customize Data Views...`. There is an option there for `Hide null array elements` that you should make sure is unticked.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer!

Comment: TG 4 SO (translation: Coming from Eclipse, I had no idea about this feature)